# How to get docker images from privacy AWS ECR repository in Vagrant

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, vagrant

I found that you can use Vagrant and Docker as a provider, That I think is so cool. [Official doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/configuration.html)

The documentation shows a section to set up using private repositories. 
**email, username, password and auth_server**

I want to know if Vagrant supports `aws ecr get-login` to get docker images from AWS Registry?

**Edited:**

I tried this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "mydocker" do |a|
    a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest"

      #Private registry
      d.email = "my@emai.com"
      d.username = "my-user"
      d.password = "my-pass"
      d.auth_server = "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

      #Custom Docker Host
      d.vagrant_machine = "dockerhost"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./dockerHost/Vagrantfile"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the output error: (Vagrant tried to make the login with the parameters)

```
Command: "docker" "login" "-u" "my-user" "-p" "my-pass" "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

Stderr: Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to setup a Vagrantfile with aws configuration (access_key_id) and reference the Vagrantfile with `config.vagrant_vagrantfile`

Comment: I edited my question with an example.

Comment: It looks like `aws ecr get-login` generate an authorizationToken to use easily the `docker login` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way using `get-authorization-token` I don't know it is the best way, but it works by the moment.

The `get-authorization-token` command creates a valid token for 12 hours. (I think this can be changed) and you can see the [official doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html)

If you are on MAC [More info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html) (does`t work with zsh console, so uses bash)

```
aws ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -D | cut -d: -f2
```

It will print the decode password and then in the Vagrantfile:

```
...
  #Private registry
  d.email = ""
  d.username = "AWS"
  d.password = "The-decoded-password"
  d.auth_server = "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
...
```

And it works.

Maybe it is necessary to generate a password that live more than 12 hours =0)

I will waiting for comments or improvements.

Comment: since vagrantfile is a ruby script you can run this command in the vagrantfile like `mytoken = ``aws ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -D | cut -d: -f2`` ` and then d.password = mytoken; it will generate a new token every time you run a vagrant command though (not sure there's limit on this)

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, so I need to use " or `` to execute the command? because shows me a syntax error.

Comment: an single backtick ` but I had issue as markdown makes it code

Comment: Tks @FrédéricHenri It works well. that means that the machine must have aws installed =0)